# In javascript, how to defined a CONST function?

Tags: javascript

I'm having some problem with chrome extension to edit one function in the page to action as i want. That i want to create a function name at the begining of the document load. Then, the exist scripts in page can not create a new function with that name, so that the must use my first function at document load.

So i want to set a CONST function, which can not set again by all other script of the page.

Is there any way to do that.

Example:

```
function unchangeable(){
 alert()
}
//some code expanding ........, and new function name unchangeable() can not be set again
function unchangeable(){ ....
 ..........
}
//this new function will fire an error, and when we call unchangeable() from now, he still create an alert()
```

Or is there any way to edit a function, before his first called?

Comment: Depending on your chrome version, `const unchangeable = function(){…}` should just work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for this.  You should be able to set `writable` (and `configurable`, I think) to false to have the function act as you want.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'unchangeable', {
    value: function(){
         alert();
    },
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks **Rocket Hazmat**, `writable: false` is the best!! And in the document of `defindProperty` i see `Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', { value: 1 });` is equal to `{writable: false,
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: false}`